# Dagger dependency conflict android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, dagger

I am using these dependencies in my project together

```
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
```

But i get this error.

> Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.squareup:javawriter' in project
>   ':app'. Resolved versions for app (2.5.0) and test app (2.1.1) differ.
>   See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

Please share any solutions for this.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The link in the exception tells you how to remedy this.

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force 'com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0'
  }
}
```

Otherwise you can use:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0'
```